# Replacing random number of characters in a string on random places

Tags: java, random

I am trying to write a program which reads a txt file in which there are 4000 or (x) words. So far i manage to write a program which you see below. It kinda words it adds (random) number of stars (*) to a randon place in a word. However here is the problem. It always add a *. How can i change that so it would add random numbers of stars to a word.

For example: lets take word Mother. 
I want a program too add a random number of * to a random place in this word.That random number of stars would be either 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 or 6 in this example. And if i would run program multiple times i would get different result like: (* are shown as ? below)

M??her , Mot??r, Mother, ?other, ??????, M????r ,ect.

Any ideas would be welcome.

```
public class random_menjava_z_zvezdico {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    String test;
    int dolzina = 0;
    String outputFile = "random_z_zvezdico.txt";

    ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList();


    try {

        File file = new File("4000_random_besed.txt");
        FileReader fileReader = new FileReader(file);
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(fileReader);
        String vrstica = bufferedReader.readLine();
        while (vrstica != null) {

            list.add(vrstica);
            vrstica = bufferedReader.readLine();
            // dolzina=list.size();
            // System.out.println(dolzina);

        }

        FileWriter fileWriter = new FileWriter(outputFile);
        PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(fileWriter);
        System.out.println("4000 besedam je bila dodana * random krat na random mestu!");
        for (int idx = 0; idx < list.size(); ++idx) {
            test = list.get(idx);
            dolzina = test.length();

            Random rGenerator = new Random();
            StringBuilder beseda = new StringBuilder(test);

            for (int i = 0; i < dolzina; ++i) {
                int randomInt = rGenerator.nextInt(dolzina);
                beseda.setCharAt(randomInt, '*');

            }
            out.println(beseda);

        }out.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();

    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would change:

```
for (int i = 0; i < dolzina; ++i) {
    int randomInt = rGenerator.nextInt(dolzina);
    beseda.setCharAt(randomInt, '*');
}
```

For:

```
for (int i = 0; i < dolzina; i++) {
    int randomInt = rGenerator.nextInt(2);
    if (randomInt > 0) {
        beseda.setCharAt(i, '*');
    }
}
```

But a better solution would be:

```
StringBuilder orig = new StringBuilder("Mother");
Random rnd = new Random();

int maskSize = rnd.nextInt(orig.length()+1);

for (int i = 0; i < maskSize; i++) {
    int pos = rnd.nextInt(orig.length());

    while (orig.charAt(pos) == '*') {
        pos++;
        if (pos >= orig.length()) {
            pos = 0;
        }
    }

    orig.setCharAt(pos, '*');
}
```

Comment: well it works bether thanks but it still doesnt add 0 stars option, i need it to add 0 or more, it works for more than 0 at the moment only

Comment: he wants the random number to be between 0 and 6 (inclusive) so instead of rGenerator.nextInt(2); I think it should be rGenerator.nextInt(7);

Comment: My previous example works with 0 or more, but the probabilty of 0 is very low. I editted the post, so all number of '*' will have the same probabilty.

Answer (score 0):

```
int randomInt = rGenerator.nextInt(7);//this gets you a number between 0 and 6 (inclusive)
```

Then from there if you want to change a random number of characters

```
int positionCount = 0;//this wiil be used to change the character at specific location starting from the first location

while(randomInt >= 0){
//change this line to randomInt > 0 if you don't want to change anything when you have zero as randomInt

  beseda.setCharAt(positionCount, '*');//this replace the next character starting from the first

  //control the values in order for the position not to exceed the string by using if statement
  if(positionCount < beseda.toString().length){
     positionCount++;
  }

  randomInt--;//decrease the random number by one to enable escape of while loop when it is done
}
```

or you can also change a character at a random position using the same random int generated previously:

```
beseda.setCharAt(randomInt, '*');
```

Answer (score 0):

I see that you didn't define the probability distribution you need for the different configurations. I'm assuming in my solution that you need a uniform probability (i.e.  "mother"/"*other"/"**ther" will all have a probability of 1/64):

```
  private static final Random rnd = new Random();

  public static String replaceRandom(String s) {
    char[] chars = s.toCharArray();
    BitSet bs = new BitSet();
    byte[] bytes = new byte[chars.length/8 + 1];
    rnd.nextBytes(bytes);
    bs = BitSet.valueOf(bytes);
    int i = bs.nextSetBit(0);
    while (i < chars.length && (i != -1)) {
      chars[i] = '*';
      i = bs.nextSetBit(i + 1);
    }

    return new String(chars);
  }
```